# Why impl RangeBounds<T> for Range<&T> requires T to be sized?

Tags: rust

https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/ops/range.rs.html#979-986

```
impl<T> RangeBounds<T> for Range<&T> {
    fn start_bound(&self) -> Bound<&T> {
        Included(self.start)
    }
    fn end_bound(&self) -> Bound<&T> {
        Excluded(self.end)
    }
}
```

As you can see, `T` is not marked with `?Sized`, which is preventing me from passing a `Range<&[u8]>` into an argument requires `impl RangeBounds<[u8]>`.

Are there some design considerations behind it? If this is intended, which is the proper way to pass a range of `[u8]`?

Answer (score 2):

It's rather unfortunate, but adding the `T: ?Sized` bound breaks type inference in code like `btreemap.range("from".."to")` because the compiler can't choose between `T = str` and `T = &str`, both of which satisfy the bounds on [`range`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html#method.range).

Some discussion of this has taken place on [PR #64327](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/64327). As far as I know there are no plans to relax the bounds on these `impl`s in the future.

Instead of a `Range<T>`, you can use a tuple of `Bound<T>`s; for example, instead of `takes_range("from".."to")`, you can write the following instead:

```
use std::ops::Bound;
takes_range((Bound::Included("from"), Bound::Excluded("to"))
```

This will work because `(Bound<&T>, Bound<&T>)` *does* implement `RangeBounds<T>` even when `T` is `!Sized`.